# Simulating drop event works in Chrome extension but not Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm trying to simulate a drop event (with the Drag and Drop API) in a browser extension's content script. Essentially, I want to simulate a user dropping an image programmatically. I have this so far:

```
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
dataTransfer.items.add(file); // File object representing image being dropped
const event = new DragEvent('drop', { dataTransfer });
document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This works great on both Chrome and Firefox when all the simulation happens natively in the browser. [This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ostqvLc/11/) works great in both browsers–if you upload a file, a drop is simulated and the image shows up in the preview.

The problem is when I try to accomplish the exact same thing with a browser extension, I run into problems in Firefox (but not Chrome). I've put together a [demo extension](https://discourse.mozilla.org/uploads/short-url/t30tD6PvylvJ8jd9NMWYeS7cY3D.zip) that accomplishes the same thing as the JSFiddle but with a content script. On Chrome, the extension injects a file input and simulates the drop perfectly (the image shows up in `#preview`):

[image]

You can see (in the free-hand circle) that `dataTransfer.files` has a length of 1–the dropped image file is in the list. But when I use the exact same extension on Firefox:

[image]

The image was uploaded (see the input) but it was not dropped and shown in the preview. From the console, you can see that `dataTransfer.files` is empty in Firefox, even though `dataTransfer.items` has the file in it!

Why is there a discrepancy here? I checked with Mozilla's compatibility checker which said my extension was cross-platform ready. [By then HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/editing.html#dom-datatransfer-files) `files` should be in sync with `items`, and no conditions AFAICT warrant an empty list on Firefox. Could this be a bug?

Comment: It could be a bug but knowing Firefox, I guess it's their historical separation of contexts for which they still provide [cloneInto and stuff like wrappedJSObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts#Sharing_content_script_objects_with_page_scripts).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the link. I did some reading on wrappedJSObject and I tried doing `new window.DataTransfer` and `new window.DragEvent` with no luck. It seems odd that Xray would mess with a specific File instance though.

Comment: `window` still refers to the content script's window, but you'd need `window.wrappedJSObject` here I think or use cloneInto explicitly. As for "odd", since content scripts run in an isolated world I'd say it's understandable they don't share the complex types because it's probably hard to change the way the separation was historically implemented.

Comment: @wOxxOm You were completely right! The file finally showed up in the `DataTransfer` object and dispatching it now works! Thank you so much–if you could post as an answer that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450450/simulating-drop-event-works-in-chrome-extension-but-not-firefox-add-on?noredirect=1#comment105083663_59450450), the problem was due to Firefox's [Xray vision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) policy that separates global objects of content scripts and page scripts (including `File`). By unwrapping the page's `DataTransfer` object instead of the content script's, I was able to simulate the drop:

```
const dataTransfer = new window.wrappedJSObject.DataTransfer();
```